# Как найти все файлы, содержащие искомый текст на linux?

Tags: linux, текст, grep, find

Хотелось бы найти способ поиска всех файлов, которые содержат заданный текст. Именно текст **внутри** файлов, а не в названиях.

Встречается такое решение:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -H 'текстДляПоиска' {} \;
```

Однако оно работает достаточно криво, как правильно это сделать?

---

<sup>Свободный перевод вопроса: [«How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/11141611)</sup>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
grep -rnw '/путь/к/папке/с/файлами' -e "шаблон"
```

- `-r` или `-R` - рекурсивный поиск.
- `-n` - вывод номера строки.
- `-w` - только целые слова.
- `-l` (нижний регистр от `L`) - вывод имени файла, где было совпадение.

Эффективности добавят следующие флаги:

- `--exclude` - Шаблон для исключения файлов, например: поиск везде, кроме файлов с расширением `.o`:

  ```
   grep --exclude=*.o -rnw '/путь/к/папке/с/файлами' -e "шаблон"
  ```
- `--include` - Поиск только в определённых файлах, например: только в файлах с расширениями `.h` и `.c`:

  ```
   grep --include=\*.{c,h} -rnw '/путь/к/папке/с/файлами' -e "шаблон"
  ```
- `--exclude-dir` и `--include-dir` - то же, только для выборки директорий, например: исключить папки `один`, `two` и любые, начинающиеся на `а`:

  ```
   grep --exclude-dir={один,two,а*} -rnw '/путь/к/папке/с/файлами' -e "шаблон"
  ```

Это отлично работает для подобных целей, остальные настройки для `grep` можно узнать, выполнив `man grep`.

---

<sup>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/11141611) от участника [@rakib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231815/rakib).</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать `grep -ilR`:

```
grep -Ril "текст-для-поиска" /
```

- `i` - игнорировать регистр.
- `R` - рекурсивный поиск.
- `l` - вывести только имя файла, а не весь результат.
- `/` - начинать поиск с корня (`root`) файловой системы.

---

<sup>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956844/11141611) от участника [@fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui).</sup>